# Why is my Tab key not working under the Windows version of Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, troubleshooting, search

Under Linux and OS X the tab in when typing in the Chrome URL bar will set a search provider. So for instance, `wiki TAB` will change the URL bar to a Wikipedia search, and then anything I type past that searches Wikipedia only.

But for some reason on my Desktop running Windows 7 using the Tab key when focus is on the URL pops the focus down to the browser.

I am running Chrome 9.0.597.98. Is this a known issue with the Windows version? Or do I have something mis-configured?

**EDIT:**
Seems like something is up with Chrome install, I've tried disabling all my extensions and clearing out my personal data, but to no avail. Is there any reliable way to remove all Chrome data and configuration and start fresh?

Two threads I found related to this issue, the popular solution of hitting space before tab is not working for me.
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=74df2020e5b9b9de&hl=en
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=6d588f2b2f98d72f&fid=6d588f2b2f98d72f00046201e9164dff&hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you aren’t typing anything else after `wiki`? In your post you have a space between them which would mean that Chrome thinks that a space is the query you want to send to Wikipedia, so when you press Tab after that, it just goes to the browser window as expected. Try typing wiki in the Omnibar without a space or anything, then look at the right end of the Omnibar. It should say *Press Tab to search Wikipedia*. Now press space and the notice goes away because you are already using the `wiki` shortcut.

Edit the keyword in the Search Engine Management dialog:
[image]

Comment: I don't get a "Press Tab to search Wikipedia" prompt.

Comment: At all‽ It should show that notice as soon as you have typed the second ‘i’ in the Omnibar.

Comment: All I see is my search history.

Comment: In the history drop-down, is there this entry: `Search Wikipedia for <enter query> - (Keyword: wiki)`?

Comment: Nope. (I can't just post nope so this is filler)

Comment: Are you using the same User Data folder for Chrome under each OS or separate ones? You may want to check your search engines as Dennis suggested because it sounds like the Wikipedia entry is using a different keyword in your Windows copy.

Comment: I am using different data folders for each install.

Comment: Then that’s probably it. In Linux/OSX, you probably set the keyword for Wikipedia to `wiki` while in Windows, it is still set to `en.wikipedia.org` (or whatever locale of Wikipedia you use). Try typing `en.wikipedia.org` in the Omnibar, chances are it will give that notice. In any case, edit the Wikipedia entry in the Search Engine management dialog and set the keyword to `wiki`.

Comment: Ok yeah that does work, the functionality seems fundamentally different the Mac and Linux version. I've never played with the search engine edit functionality and I can search random sites like metacritic.com and giantbomb.com. So while the wiki keyword change does work, it still isn't fully functioning.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding the feature, but look at the Mac version I have all these search engines registered that I need added manually. I can also start typing wikipedia, and after typing just the w, I can hit tab and get the option to search wikipedia.org.

Comment: You said the search engines are registered that you need added manually. Do you mean that they are available on your Mac copy, but not the Windows one? I assume that most of them have the full domain name as the keyword (eg foobar.com as opposed to foobar). That’s because you have visited those sites and performed a search at some point using your Mac, but not under Windows.

Comment: Whenever you perform a search on a webpage, Chrome adds that search field to its list of Search Engines, using the domain name of the site as the keyword. So if you perform a search at **foobar.org**, from that point on, you can use `foobar.org` as a shortcut instead of going to the page and manually performing the search. For example to search foobar.org for *blah* you would now enter `foobar.org blah` in the Omnibar. I don’t have a Mac, but I imagine that it should perform similarly to the Windows version. You can edit the Wikipedia entry and set the keyword to `w` to make it work the same.

Comment: Yeah I think that is it. I just started using Chrome on Windows so I need to train it for a little before it as functional as my other installations.

Comment: Not really, you can manually enter your main Search Engines. You’ll also want to weed out the ones you don’t use because Chrome automatically adds *every* search that you use, so you’ll have a lot of cruft in there from sites that you visited and performed a search on only once.

Answer (score 1):

Right click in the URL bar and select `Edit Search Engines...`. You may need to tweak some of the entries. I'm not sure what changed about Wikipedia, but I found that I had to manually fix that particular one. It was set to "en.wikipedia.org" and I changed it to "wikipedia.org".

Comment: It's not just Wikipedia that isn't working, it's that entire functionality.